# Python[5285:92090] TSM AdjustCapsLockLEDForKeyTransitionHandling - _ISSetPhysicalKeyboardCapsLockLED Inhibit in using library keyboard

Tags: python, macos, keyboard

I am using keyboard on my macOS 14. It looks like this:

```py
import keyboard as kb

now_key = ""
lk = None

def callback(event):
    global now_key, lk
    a = str(event)
    if a[-5:] == 'down)':
        if a[14:-6] not in ("shift", "right shift", "ctrl", "right ctrl", "caps lock"):
            now_key = a[14:-6]
    if a[-3:] == "up)":
        now_key = ''

kb.hook(callback)
```

But when I tried to use it, my program gives me a problem:

> Python[5285:92090] TSM AdjustCapsLockLEDForKeyTransitionHandling - _ISSetPhysicalKeyboardCapsLockLED Inhibit

I can use it in Windows, but in macOS, it cannot run successfully.

I tried https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdREmCHrnYw, but it doesn't work.